# When i use type keyguard dialog then my screen stops working

Tags: java, android

I am developing a Lock Screen App that will lock the screen as well as apps that the user want to.
Lock can be pin code or pattern lock and so far now when I activate a pin code or pattern lock then a lock screen appears on the screen when user Reboot or off the screen, the problem I am facing right now is that, I can't disable my Home button and Task manager button.

What I have tried soo far is
I have added the

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
```

after adding this, Home button and Task Manager button is still enabled and my screen freezes, if I touch something on the screen its not performing anything and when I press Home button the lock screen disappear.

I also have added this too

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        return;
    }

    // Handle button clicks
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, android.view.KeyEvent event) {

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
                || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)
                || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
                || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA)) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {

            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    // handle the key press events here itself
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP
                || (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
                || (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

after adding this, back button is disabled successfully working but Home button is still enabled and funtioning.

Comment: i think your question is valid and shows effort (so i've upvoted) but the `android-studio` tag is only meant to be used if your question involves features of the android studio IDE, you don't add that tag just because you're using android studio, so i've removed it :)

Comment: Ok thank you for your modification